# Academic information

Tags: titles

Is there any package that extends article class, so formating paper title can became a little easier and cleaner? In particular email, role, university name ,....

I mean a clean preamble like following:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\title{Easy LaTeX}
\begin[columns=3]{authors}
   \author[email=s@aut.ac.ir, university=Amirkabir,city=Tehran,country=Iran]{B. Baxci }
   \author[email=ss@aut.ac.ir,university=Amirkabir,department=IT and computer,city=Tehran,country=Iran]{A. Naseri }
   \author[email=far@aut.ac.ir,afeliation=Nano Research Center,city=Tehran,country=Iran]{F. Farhadi }
\end{authors}

\begin{document}
% all good stuff 
\end{document}
```

If there is no package, what is best practice for outputting common academic information.

Comment: There are some experimental things in the LaTeX3 archive (see `xfm` and `xmetadata`), but I am not aware of a 'release' package that works quite the way you'd like. Note that you mixing up two things: how to input author metadata, and how to print it. I suspect a good interface would separate them out.

Comment: The [authblk](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package provides some help in this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elsevier [provides](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsarticle) the `elsarticle`-class, which allows easy input of author metadata. However, I'm not certain about possible licensing issues, so please check that before publishing such a document online.

The email-adresses are displayed as footnotes at the bottom of the first page and therefore not shown in the screenshots here.

[image: First option with footnotes]

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\journal{TeX.sx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Easy \LaTeX}

\author[ami]{B. Baxci\corref{cor1}}
\ead{s@aut.ac.ir}

\author[ami]{A. Naseri}
\ead{ss@aut.ac.ir}

\author[nano]{F. Farhadi}
\ead{sss@aut.ac.ir}

\address[ami]{Amirkabir University, IT and Computer Department, Teheran, Iran}
\address[nano]{Nano Research Center, Teheran, Iran}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
    key1 \sep key2 \sep key3
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\Blindtext[2][3]
\end{document}
```

Another possibility, which takes up a bit more space:
[image: Second option]

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\journal{TeX.sx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Easy \LaTeX}

\author{B. Baxci\corref{cor1}}
\ead{s@aut.ac.ir}
\address{Amirkabir University, IT and Computer Department, Teheran, Iran}

\author{A. Naseri\corref{cor2}}
\ead{ss@aut.ac.ir}
\address{Amirkabir University, IT and Computer Department, Teheran, Iran}

\author{F. Farhadi\corref{cor2}}
\ead{sss@aut.ac.ir}
\address{Nano Research Center, Teheran, Iran}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
    key1 \sep key2 \sep key3
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\Blindtext[2][3]
\end{document}
```